# Autofit for inline equations

Tags: equations, inline

I am trying to use an inline equation to list bunch o tuples. However, I it does not automatically go to next line. I am doing it manually, but this time it looks ugly. By the way I am writing in a two column template, so I have limited space at each line.
Here is what I do:

> ${x_i,\;y_i }$= $ {{60,45},\; {60,90},\;{60,135},\;{60,180},\;{60,225},\; \ {100,90},\; {100,160},\;{100,225}} $

Is there a way to automatically do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to distinguish which commas are eligible for breaks; so I suggest a command for it:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\bc}{,\penalty0 \;}

\begin{document}
$x_i,y_i=60,45\bc 60,90\bc 60,135\bc 60,180\bc 60,225\bc 100,90\bc 100,160\bc 100,225$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't overuse `\;` (it's wrong between `x_i` and `y_i`) and also braces: the ones you have in your example are all useless.

Comment: the `\;` before the penalty will leave a space at the end of the line if it's broken there.  it would be better to put the penalty before the space.  (tested; space at the beginning of line is ignored after break.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton You're right, of course.